# Runtime.ImportModuleError when deploying Lambda with Amplify

Tags: python-3.x, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway, aws-amplify, pipenv

■Problem

When I run a Lambda deployed using amplify push in a project created with Amplify, the error [ERROR] Runtime.ImportModuleError: Unable to import module 'index' occurs.

■ What I want to achieve in the first place

I want to use LangChain in a Lambda invoked asynchronously from another Lambda to return answers to questions input by the front desk from Pinecone to the front desk.

■ Steps to be taken

・Create Amplify project by Amplify init

・Create API Gateway and Lambda(Lambda1) which is connected to API Gateway by "Amplify add api".

・Create asynchronous Lambda (hereafter called Lambda2) by "Amplify add function".

・When deploying the above Amplify, API Gateway, Lambda1 and Lambda2 by "amplify push", the error [ERROR] Runtime.ImportModuleError: Unable to import module 'index' occurs in Lambda2. Runtime.ImportModuleError: Unable to import module 'index'" occurred.

■ Probable cause

pipenv is not installing pinecone-client, langchain, and requests properly.

Reason: Because this error doesn't happen when I comment out these three packages.

■ What I tried

・reinstalled pinecone-client, langchain, requests with pipenv install

Reference
Lambda2 source

```
    import json
    import os
    from dotenv import load_dotenv

    # Comment out the following or this error will occur.
    # -------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    import pinecone
    from langchain.document_loaders import PyPDFLoader
    from langchain.embeddings.openai import OpenAIEmbeddings
    from langchain.text_splitter import RecursiveCharacterTextSplitter
    from langchain.vectorstores import Pinecone

    from langchain.llms import OpenAI
    from langchain.chains.question_answering import load_qa_chain

    import requests
    # -------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    # Omit the following
```

Lamba2 Pipfile

```
    [[source]]
    name = "pypi"
    url = "https://pypi.org/simple"
    verify_ssl = true

    [dev-packages]

    [packages]
    src = {editable = true, path = "./src"}
    langchain = "*"
    flake8 = "*"
    black = "*"
    isort = "*"
    pytest = "*"
    mypy = "*"
    nox = "*"
    pre-commit = "*"
    openai = "*"
    pypdf = "*"
    pinecone-client = "*"
    tiktoken = "*"
    load-dotenv = "*"
    requests = "*"
    \[requires\]
    python_version = "3.8"
```

■ Environment

OS：MacOS Monterey 12.6.7

amplify：12.2.2

Python：3.8.16

pipenv：2023.7.23

Comment: the `langchain` module is not good: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ygehmBjwtiw&ab_channel=DarrenLefcoe

Comment: Sorry for my late reply. Thank you for your advice.